# Эффект сепии в bmp

Tags: c++, bmp

Всем доброе время суток. Интересен алгоритм фильтра сепия для bmp файла. Как я понял необходимо RGB перевести в палитру YCbCr а дальше какие мои действия?

Comment: Не нужно преобразование, судя по написанному в интернетах, сепия может быть реализована в RGB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outputRed = (inputRed * .393) + (inputGreen *.769) + (inputBlue * .189)
outputGreen = (inputRed * .349) + (inputGreen *.686) + (inputBlue * .168)
outputBlue = (inputRed * .272) + (inputGreen *.534) + (inputBlue * .131)
```

Источник - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-convert-images-to-grayscale-and-sepia-tone-using-c/

Comment: кстати светлые участки очень сильно заполняет синим цветом

Comment: Думаю, можно покрутить коэффициеты и настроить результат.

Answer (score 2):

Не превышайте значение 255 и синевы не будет.